# How to merge multiple input and embeddings into single input layer

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, embedding

I have various inputs, some that need embedding. I have been able to create them all as seen below:

[image]

I can then concatenate them all, for the following:

[image]

However, my disconnect is where to go from here. I have built the following autoencoder, but I am not sure how to "stack" the previous embedding+input mix on top of this flow:

[image]

So, **how do I make the input layer whats already been defined above?** I tried setting the first "encoder" part to take in `merge_models`, but it fails:

[image]

Code is the following:

```
num_input = Input(shape=scaled_data.shape[1], name='input_number_features')
models.append(num_input)
inputs.append(num_input)  

binary_input = Input(shape=binary_data.shape[1], name='input_binary_features')
models.append(binary_input)
inputs.append(binary_input)  
  
for var in cols_to_embed :
    model = Sequential()
    no_of_unique_cat  = data[var].nunique()
    embedding_size = np.ceil(np.sqrt(no_of_unique_cat))
    embedding_size = int(embedding_size)
    print(var + " - " + str(no_of_unique_cat) + ' unique values to ' + str(embedding_size))
    inpt = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,),\
                                 name='input_' + '_'.join(\
                                 var.split(' ')))
    embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(no_of_unique_cat, embedding_size,trainable=True,\
                                      embeddings_initializer=tf.initializers\
                                      .random_normal)(inpt)
    embed_rehsaped = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(embed)
    models.append(embed_rehsaped)
    inputs.append(inpt)

merge_models = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(models)

# Input Layer
input_dim = merge_models.shape[1]
input_layer = Input(shape = (input_dim, ), name = 'input_layer')

# Encoder
encoder = Dense(16, activation='relu')(input_layer)
encoder = Dense(8, activation='relu')(encoder)
encoder = Dense(4, activation='relu')(encoder)

# Bottleneck
z = Dense(2, activation='relu')(encoder)

# Decoder
decoder = Dense(4, activation='relu')(z)
decoder = Dense(8, activation='relu')(decoder)
decoder = Dense(16, activation='relu')(decoder)
decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation='elu')(decoder) # intentionally using 'elu' instead of 'reul'

# Autoencoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
autoencoder = Model(inputs = input_layer, 
                    outputs = decoder,
                    name = 'ae_toy_example')
```

Comment: simply passing merge_models to the first encoder layer and define your model in this way: autoencoder = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = decoder, name = 'ae_toy_example') works! The error is because you used input_layer instead of inputs in model definition

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I tried this in the third image above with `encoder = Dense(16, activation='relu')(merge_models)`, but the error is likely related to how I specify one of the inputs.

Comment: in the image (and in the code) autoencoder is Model(inputs = input_layer,  outputs = decoder, name = 'ae_toy_example')... it should be Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = decoder, name = 'ae_toy_example')

Comment: Thanks - that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `merge_models` into the first encoder layer in this way:

```
encoder = Dense(16, activation='relu')(merge_models)
```

then you should define your final model in this way:

```
Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = decoder, name = 'ae_toy_example')
```

and **NOT** as:

```
Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = decoder, name = 'ae_toy_example')
```